# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to allow lossy inserts in MySQL 5.7+. My JDBC URL looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useSSL=false&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false&sessionVariables=sql_mode=NO_STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Why do I get this exception?

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Variable 'sql_mode' can't be set to the value of 'NO_STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Review the documentation for SQL mode here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html

There is no mode named `NO_STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`.

You either use `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, or you leave that mode out of the sql_mode.